# Return false doesn't stop the code in ajax $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I execute an ajax request using `$.post`, this is my code:

```
$.post(postUrl, postData, function(response)
{
      if(response.status == "SUCCESS")
      {
             updateConfirmFrame();
      }
      else
      {
             return false;
      }
 }, 'json');
```

now if the response return `SUCCESS` the code continue calling a function that unlock some control, but if an exception is handled, so the code should blocked. Now I've put an alert in `return false;` condition and the alert is printed correctly but, the return false doesn't stop the code. I don't want that the code continue the execution. I also tried with `throw Exception` but doesn't working. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
$.post(postUrl, postData)

.done(function(response)
{
    if(response.status == "SUCCESS")
    {
        updateConfirmFrame();
    }
    else
    {
            alert("error"); //The problem is here
            return false;
     }
 })
 .fail(function(err)
 {
       return false;
 });

alert("hi wor")
```

Comment: What do you mean stop execution?  Ajax is asynchronous.  The logic past the ajax call will continue to process while your ajax call is being processed.  Any logic you only want to execute in the case of a success should be placed in the success callback.

Comment: you should handle it the way ajax is supposed to be handled with `.done()` or `.fail()` to handle the success or failure of your code but also consider that javascript is linear so while your asynchronous code is waiting to resolve your javascript will continue - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: ...there isn't even any code in that function after the `return false;`...so how exactly are you coming to the conclusion that it's still executing code after returning false? Did you put the alert _after_ the `return false;`? You realize return only stops further execution of code _in that particular function_, right?

Comment: Also, your function IS the success handler...so why are you trying to check it for success? That argument is just the data returned from the URL

Answer (score 1):

Use that:

```
$.post(url, postdata)
 .done(function(response) {

  })
 .fail(function(err) {
   // error
 });
```

The syntax you used is `$.post(postUrl, postData, success_callback, fail_callback);`

Comment: I put return false in the fail function, the alert appear but the code doesn't stop the execution :\

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito - What alert? An alert on the next line of code after `return false;`? You've got to give us an actual example of a line of code executing AFTER the function returns.

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito - There's no lines of code after the `return false;` in that updated code either. So what are you saying is still executing after `return false;`?

Comment: Sorry I missing the alert, how you can see the "hi work" is displayed, but shouldn't displayed 'cause before there is return false; fired..

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito: you can't stop the code execution, or you have to put it all in a function and call that function in the .done() call.

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito - `return` only stops the rest of the code in THAT FUNCTION from executing (i.e. it returns the function's end value). It does not stop all of JS in the browser from executing...there's absolutely no reason that line at the bottom, that is not even part of the returned function, wouldn't run.

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito You can't. You should design the flow differently.

Comment: And for information, the callback in .done() is executed once the request has been sent and received. And as js in only 1 thread, the callback in .done() is called once the rest of your code is executed. So if you requires the API response, you need to put all your code in a function and call it only if .done().

Answer (score 1):

`return` statements only return the function they are within, stopping further code execution *in that function*. They do not stop JS code execution in general.

The alert statement you are saying shouldn't run because you've done `return false;` is not in the function returning false. It would not be affected by the fact that some other function returned false. It absolutely should run.

---

On top of that, the success function for your post call is an event callback. It is created, but does not run until the actual loading of the file happens, which is gonna be long after other code outside your ajax stuff finishes. So the code in that function isn't even gonna be executing before that alert takes place.